# I do not understand why my constraints are not continuous?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am optimizing an inverted pendulum for minimum force using trapezoidal collocation and scipy minimize.

I am using the SLSQP method since my problem is nonlinear. When running the code, I get this error:

```
[Running] python -u 
  status: 6
 success: False
    njev: 1
    nfev: 32
     fun: 0.0
       x: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem'
     jac: array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.49011612e-08,   1.49011612e-08,   1.49011612e-08,
         1.49011612e-08,   1.49011612e-08,   1.49011612e-08,
         0.00000000e+00])
     nit: 1
```

From looking around, it seems this is due to having nonlinear constraints. Here is my code at the moment:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize



#parameters
m1 = 1
m2 = 0.3
g = 9.81
l = 0.5
dmax = 2.0
umax = 20.0
T = 2
d = 1
h = 0.2

# (x0,u0) (x1,u1) ....
# +-------+--------+-------+------+--------+------> 1
# y = [x0, u0, x1, u1, ..., x5, u5]
# Alt.:
# y = [x0, x1, x2, ..., u0, ... u5]
# x = y[:24]
# u = y[-6:] = y[24:]

#Objective 
def objective(x):      
    return np.sum(x[-6:]**2)


#EOM's SS
# dx_i = statespace(xi[0], xi[1], xi[2], xi[3], ui)
def statespace(y1,y2,ydot1,ydot2,u):    # Should only provide the 4 states; the others are fixed paramters.

    dy1 = ydot1
    dy2 = ydot2
    dydot1 = ((l*m2*np.sin(y1)*y1*y1) + u + (m2*g*np.cos(y1)*np.sin(y1))) / (m1 + m2*(1-np.cos(y1)**2))
    dydot2 = -1*((l*m2*np.cos(y2)*np.sin(y2)*y2*y2) + u*np.cos(y2) + ((m1+m2)*g*np.sin(y2))) / (l*m1 + l*m2*(1-np.cos(y2)**2))
    return np.array([dy1,dy2,dydot1,dydot2])      


#trap(y) == 0
def trap(y,f=statespace):
    x = y[:24].reshape(6,4)
    u = y[24:]
    c = np.zeros((5,4))
    for k in range(5):
         f1 = f(x[k+1,0], x[k+1,1], x[k+1,2], x[k+1,3], u[k+1])
         f0 = f(x[k,0],x[k,1],x[k,2],x[k,3],u[k])
         c[k] = x[k+1]-x[k]-(h/2)*(f1+f0)
         return c.reshape(-1)



#Initial Guess
#steps = 
#x0 = [# of states + # of controls]x[# of steps] * steps  
x0 = np.zeros(30)


# End points:

# Starting point:
def constraint_start(y):
    x0 = y[:4]
    return x0

#End point
def constraint_end(y):
    xf = [d,np.pi,0,0]
    return xf

#bounds
b = (-dmax,dmax)
c = (-umax,umax)  
bnds = [(b), (-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf), 
(-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),
(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(-np.inf, np.inf),(c),(c),(c),(c),(c),(c)]

con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_start}
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_end}
con3 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': trap}
cons = (con1,con2,con3)                  

sol = minimize(objective, x0, method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons) 
print(sol)
```

However, I believe the culprit is my second constraint. I do not think I am properly constraining the endpoints of collocation points. I have tried various things but keep getting the above error. My current code has my last attempt. I am supposed to have boundary constraints as shown in the image below. I appreciate any and all help.

[Boundary Constraints for Inverted Pendulum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPi9s.png)